# Producing a Python executable (py2exe, pyinstaller, etc.) wihtout lots of subfolders like "tcl", etc

Tags: python, tcl, installation, py2exe, pyinstaller

I use `py2exe`, with the special option in order to produce one file only (`'bundle_files': 1`). It works.

But in the output folder `\dist\`, there are subfolders like `tcl\`, `tk\`, etc.

**Is it possible to pack these folders inside the main .exe file, or in a .dll, instead of having this extra folder with lots of files ?**

(The same is true with PyInstaller).

Comment: Are the sub-directories too large, or just unsightly? If it's the latter, you could make them invisible...

Comment: It's just because I don't want a lot of folders if it's not needed (*Simple is better than complex.*)

Answer (score 2):

```
pyinstaller -F <your_python.py>
```

This will make only ONE big EXE. Without need any Python DLL, or TCL dirs, or anything.